# Carrierwave/Rails/CSS - HTML style attribute being generated seemingly automatically

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave with rails 4. I need image upload functionality on a few models in my app and it's working great on all of them except one. On the adverts model, all the uploaded images seem to have the following HTML style attributes being generated automatically (or seemingly so):

```
<img alt="Advert" src="..image_path_is_correct..." width="0" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 1px 1px;">
```

My form is declared like so:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @advert] do |f| %>

  <div class="form-field-area-centered">
    <p class="form-label"><%= f.label :advert_image, "New Advert" %></p>
    <p class="form-field"><%= f.file_field :advert_image %></p>
  </div>  

    <%= f.submit "SAVE", :class => "button button-green button-login" %>

<% end %>
```

and in my view I have:

```
<div class="advert-area">
    <%= image_tag @first_post.user.adverts.last.advert_image_url %>
</div>
```

I'm kind of at a loss as to what could be causing this so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `Visibility:hidden` also present in your form file field also?

Comment: @NitinVerma No it's not